# AngularJS text input with ng-model but needs default value not working with value= or ng-init=

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an account form with many inputs.  One of them below:

```
<input class="form-control " placeholder="First Name" type="text" ng-model="account.first_name" ng-init="account.first_name=user.account.first_name">
```

I have a service in my controller that returns all of the user's information.  I'm trying to, in inputs, show the current information on file.

I want this in an input so they can also change (update) it.

However, when I set `value="{{user.account.first_name}}"` which is returned by my API from my service and set equal to `$scope.user`, it shows nothing in the input.

I searched for answers on SO and found a few that suggested `ng-init`, which still didn't work.

I've also tried `ng-bind`, `ng-value`, and putting these before I set `ng-model`.

How can I do  this?

Edit:

Here is my account controller.  The service just has `return $http.get('/api/account');`

```
app.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope, Account) {

    Account.show()
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.user = data;
        });
```

`data` is a JSON schema like so:

```
{"account": {}, "documents": {}}
```

But with data inside.

Comment: Post your service where you retrieve `user`. All you do is set `$scope.account.first_name = "some name"` and your model will update. You don't need `ng-init`

Comment: yep, not enoupgh information. But as I guess, u need smth like: ng-model="userCopy.account.first_name" ng-init="userCopy = user".

Comment: `ng-model="user.account.first_name"` perhaps?

Comment: This isn't a problem with getting the data at all.  The API returns the right data.  I console.log() in my controller and it logs the data.  It's a problem with the view.

Comment: it is a problem that your view does not update because it is not related to 'user' object, so when it changes view remains the same

Comment: @akonsu that shows the data but then when clicking my save button it POSTS the same data, not the data in the input.

Comment: I just need it to default to a value, that value being user.account.first_name, user.account.last_name, etc. which is attached to the `$scope`

Comment: since you do not show all the code I cannot tell why it does not update the model. I guess this is because something creates a child scope. try `ng-model="$parent.user....."`.

Comment: Is there no way to do this then?  Isn't it logical to you to be able to have a text input with a default value from a database that can be changed, POSTed to the API on `ng-click` to then update the user account?  This is so simple in jQuery.

Comment: the whole world does this. hence it must be possible.

Comment: The whole world doesn't use Angular.

Comment: ok. I give up. sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do that in controller after you get data from your service

```
      Account.show()
     .success(function (data) {
     $scope.user = data;

     //set account.first_name here
     $scope.account = {
         first_name: $scope.user.account.first_name
     };
     //or you can use angular.copy(source, destination)
     angular.copy(data.account, $scope.account)

 });
```

Comment: There's ~30 key-value pairs I'd prefer not to do this if there's a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you save yourself the headache and drop the account business off the model. I don't see what function it serves, just use the user object. Double alternative:

In your controller:
$scope.account = angular.copy($scope.user);

Comment: Added this below `$scope.user` and I'm still not getting the value in the input.